# What if security is compromised by site that is certified by valid CA?

Tags: security, authentication, certificate, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am looking into web security topic and just wondering what if your financial, credit card or private information is misused or compromised by a website having valid seal of some certification Authority?

1. Does CA take any legal action against the offending entity in
   addition to revoking certificate?
2. How does the CA know of any irregularity?
3. Does CA carry out any audit of the entities they certify? or is it not their part in the job?

Answer (score 0):

Certificate Authorities have one primary job -> they receive requests for certificates, validate that the person requesting a certain certificate is actually authorized to that name (if I want an examplesite.com certificate, do I own examplesite.com?), and then issue it to the authorized party. That's it.